# How to align the image button to the left and to the right in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I have a grid with two image buttons, in this way:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Para el menú, como por ejemplo settings.-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Button HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="0"
            Command="{Binding MostrarRegistroHorarioEnMapaCommand}"
            ImageSource="mapa.svg"/>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="1"
        ImageSource="refrescar.svg"
        Command="{Binding GetRegistrosHorariosCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that each image is centered in the column of the grid, but I would like to align the first ImageButton to the left and the second to the right.

I have tried to use the HorizontalOptions, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: When I copied your code, I did not encounter any problems. I works as you expected.

Comment: Extra information: All image source strings should be `.png`, MAUI converts your `.svg` files to `png`. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: First question: OS. Second question, is this Grid nested in another control. The second question is super important.

Comment: I have tested your code in my project and the button's location is correct.